# Joining multiple collections on application level with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a simple chat service using mongoose and nodejs.

I have two models one for messaging another for read info;

```
var ChatModel = new Schema({
    to: String,
    from: String,
    message: String,
    time: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var InfoModel = new Schema({
    reader: String,
    from: String,
    time: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

When someone (reader) checks his/her incoming messages from someone else (from) I simply put a record on InfoModel.

I want to find out the distinct senders who sent messages to (lets say) T1 with read info.

```
            Chat.distinct('from', {to: 'T1'})
            .then(
            function (data) {                 
                res.json(data);
            })
```

having find the distinct senders I somehow need to iterate through the senders and fetch the latest message times for each. Here is what I tried to do but did not work

```
            Chat.distinct('from', {to: 'T1'})
            .then(
            function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    Chat.findOne({from: data[i], to:'T1'}, 'time', {sort: {'time': -1}})
                        .then(function(d){
                            ... I need to fetch from InfoModel and compare the dates for read/unread information
                        }

                    )
                }
                res.json(result);
            })
```

but obviously this approach did not work as I need all the records came from findOne ready and get the info from InfoModel.

Well simply I need something sync or I should think in async way, have no idea how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous functions in a for loop is not a good practice.

The for loop doesn't wait for async functions to call it's callback ( which is finishing it's job ). It would iterate whole loop so fast because it doesn't have to wait async functions, and then fires `res.json(result);` even that first `Chat.findOne({from: data[0] ....` haven't finish yet it's job and invoke the callback.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Chat.findOne({from: data[i], to:'T1'}, 'time', {sort: {'time': -1}})
    .then(function(d){
        // ... I need to fetch from InfoModel and compare the dates for read/unread information
    })
}

/**
 This res.json would be fired even the first Chat.findOne not yet finished.
*/
res.json(result);
```

You should make the iteration wait untill all the data are fetched from Models and then you could do `res.json(result);` in their callback.

You could always control your async data flow with this awesome [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) node.js npm module.

Hope you nailed that problem!  :)